# MySQLi fetch_field and predefined constants for data type

Tags: php, mysqli, constants

There is a little table with fields

```
COLUMN_TYPE
--------------
int(10) unsigned
float
decimal(9,3)
varchar(255)
text
timestamp
enum('Yes','No','Dunno')
set('Nsk','SPb','MSk','WRl')
tinyint(1)
```

API function mysqli->fetch_row() give me "type" property with numerical code for each type. Say data type is 7, float 4, enum 254 and so on. But values of the predefined constants like MYSQLI_TYPE_ENUM looks like different that mysqli 'type' has. When I tryin following code

```
echo '<br/>', $finfo->type, '<br/>', 'MYSQLI_TYPE_ENUM=', MYSQLI_TYPE_ENUM;
```

where $finfo->type currently points to enum field I have result such as

```
MYSQLI_TYPE_ENUM=247
254
```

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE I meant fetch_field, not fetch_row

Comment: Err... what particular API this fetch_row() function belongs to? May be fetch_field you mean?

Comment: Sorry, _fetch_field_ of course.

Comment: So I thrown away predefined constants